# For applying Agile methodology in project which is being writthen in C#, I must follow MVC approach or I can use ordinary way?

Tags: agile

For applying Agile methodology in project which is being written in C#, I must follow MVC approach or I can use ordinary way?

Because of unit test at the end of each iteration every module should be tested separately that I think it is not possible in C# ordinary way, is it correct or not, please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Agile approach is technology independent. ASP.NET MVC makes it easier but you can test common ASP.NET WebForms as well. You just need to write your application testable. Also few additional points:

- Agile doesn't mean that you will write unit tests for your code. Testing is only part of agile process.
- Testing application doesn't mean writing only unit tests. There are also other type of tests which are used in agile as well - integration tests, end-to-end tests, performance tests, etc.
- It is not correct assumption that tests are done at the end of the iteration. Test are created continuously as the feature is implemented. In some agile practices they are even implemented before the feature itself (test driven development). Writing test at the end of the iteration is way back to waterfall and to the process which doesn't work because if some feature take more time you will not have enough time to test it or even worse to test more features. That is wrong.